# Matlab code checker

Tags: matlab, save, eval, metaprogramming

I am doing a program for students. They can load their matlab code in the matlab program, and the program is supposed to execute the student's code and check if the output is correct, and if is not, the program must point out the wrong line code. So I think this is a kind of metaprogramming. Right now I am trying to use the eval() function in order to execute the input text as code, but I don't know if this is a good idea. Also I am having problems to maintain the variables in the workspace because when I change from one method to another, the workspace variables are reset, so I am thinking in solving this problem saving and loading the workspace in a file, but may be you can suggest other and better ideas.

For now, we have predefined exercises the student must solve, the output of the program is always one or several images, because this is for image processing class. Here one example of code:

```
X=double(LENNA_G);
Y=medfilt2(X,[7 7]);
ps=psnr(Y,X,255);
disp(sprintf('%f[dB]',ps));

subplot(1,3,1);
imagesc(X,[0 255]);
colormap(gray(256))
axis image

subplot(1,3,2);
imagesc(Y,[0 255]);
axis image

subplot(1,3,3);
imagesc(X-Y,[-10 10]);
axis image
```

After executing code, the resulting images are compared to correct images (predefined images), and must be the same. If they are not, then the program must point out at least the line of code in which the error could be. I don't know if I made my self understood =/.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will you post some of your work here or what you have tried?

Comment: Could you give an example for such an exercise? I can't imagine a reasonable way to identify a wrong line of code.

Comment: I added new information I omitted before. My code is not working right now but I made a loop that reads the student's code line by line and executes each line with the eval() function.

Comment: I don't see an approach of finding the exact line of code in an easy fashion. If the exercise consists of several steps, you could save the result after each step in a cell array and compare this one somehow. The cell array can be the output of the student's function and you can call it with your evaluation-script. Then you can tell in which sub-exercise the result starts to differ from your expected version. Of course you can create predefined error-images to identify common mistakes. I suggest not to use the `eval`-function unless it is *absolutely* needed.

Comment: You say you want to code data, but then you write "the output of the program is always one or several images". That's something else, verifying data can be done with much less effort, but there is no way to track errors back to a wrong code line. I recommend to take a look at cody for some inspiration (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/cody/)

Comment: @Matt you suggest me to evaluate each step of the exercise and save the result of it in a cell array, I think is a great idea, but how can I evaluate each step without using eval() function?, do you have some idea in mind?

Comment: @Daniel, thank you for your suggestion, I do need inspiration u.u. I also think that tracking the error will be a very difficult task =/

Comment: Each student creates a function with a the cell-array as output and your image as input (or whatever input you want). The best is when you provide a template and the students just write the code. This could be a prototype: `function results = exercise1_studentXY(sourceimage)`. In your script you call their functions directly and they get evaluated. At the end you have the resulting images in the cell array `results`. They can then be compared inside your script to give a feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, I would propose this solution. Hand out a template to your students:

```
function solution=exercise1(image1,image2)
%A) extract the r, g and b channel from the imag1e
solution.a.r=nan;
solution.a.g=nan;
solution.a.b=nan;
%B) convert the image2 to greyscale
solution.b=nan;
end
```

Then you can call the function exercise1 and compare field by field, everything you need is a recursive comparison of structs which outputs the fieldnames with differences. You could also provide a script template instead of a function template, but then your students must create separate files for their functions. This way the functions can be created in the same file, keeping them private and avoiding namespace conflicts.

Comment: I was not even thinking of a struct. But this gives definitely a better way of addressing since fieldsnames tell more about the content than just a number. Even the handling of subexercises or steps gets easier like this.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas @Matt and Daniel, I think this could solve my problem, I will work in this program and I'll let you know how it goes.